# CodeBuild+GitHub - How can I build a branch upon PULL_REQUEST_MERGED?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

**The need** - when merging a pull-request to a branch, I want CodeBuild to build the latest branch's commit, **not** the pull-request.
I'm using CloudFormation, here's the triggers snippet:

```
 Triggers:
   Webhook: true
   FilterGroups:
     - - Type: EVENT
         Pattern: PULL_REQUEST_CREATED, PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED, PULL_REQUEST_REOPENED
       - Type: BASE_REF
         Pattern: !Sub "refs/heads/${GithubBranchName}$"
         ExcludeMatchedPattern: false
```

I've tried adding PULL_REQUEST_MERGED in the same CodeBuild project, but it builds the PR.

I've also tried creating a new CodeBuild project with PULL_REQUEST_MERGED only, and I tweaked the BASE_REF and HEAD_REF, but still no luck, the pull-request is built, instead of the branch.

Even though I'm using CloudFormation, feel free to reply with screenshots referring to AWS Console.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue, I had to use the PUSH trigger instead of PULL_REQUEST_MERGED, and I also had corrupted webhooks in my GitHub repository.

So this is how I solved it - I've deleted all webhooks in GitHub, deleted the Codebuild project, added the PUSH trigger, here's the triggers snippet:

```
  Triggers:
    Webhook: true
    FilterGroups:
      - - Type: EVENT
          Pattern: PULL_REQUEST_CREATED, PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED, PULL_REQUEST_REOPENED
        - Type: BASE_REF
          Pattern: !Sub "refs/heads/${GithubBranchName}$"
          ExcludeMatchedPattern: false
      - - Type: EVENT
          Pattern: PUSH
        - Type: HEAD_REF
          Pattern: !Sub "refs/heads/${GithubBranchName}$"
          ExcludeMatchedPattern: false              
  SourceVersion: !Sub ${GithubBranchName}
```

Recreated my CodeBuild project, so it recreated the relevant webhooks, now everything works as expected.